On AWS Athena, how to write a passthrough query that specifies the datasource?
From the AWS documentation, it says that I can use something like:
SELECT * FROM TABLE(
        system.query(
            query => 'SELECT * FROM customer LIMIT 10'
        ))

... to pass the query straight to the connector. And its working fine when I use the query editor on Athena AWS console.
I have integrated Athena with Metabase and that same query doesn't work on Metabase because it doesn't specify the data source on the query. My Metabase integration is such that it's important that I'm able to query from multiple data sources. But, at the same time, I want to be able to use passthrough.
How can I specify the data source on the SQL query that uses the passthrough?
I'm hoping there is some param like data_source that I can pass to system.query to specify the data source to use on the passthrough.
